# Convert Json date to java date

Tags: java, json, datetime, gson

My json respons contains a **CreatedOn** Date:

```
{
"CreatedOn" : "\/Date(1406192939581)\/"
}
```

I need to convert **CreatedOn** to a simple date format and **count the days of difference from CreatedOn Date to Present Date.**

When I debug the below code string **CreatedOn** showing a null value. How come?

```
JSONObject store = new JSONObject(response);

if (response.contains("CreatedOn"))
{
    String CreatedOn = store.getString("CreatedOn");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JSONObject store = new JSONObject(response);
if(store.has("CreatedOn")) {
  Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(store.getLong("CreatedOn"));
  Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
  System.out.println(date);
}
```

or

```
JSONObject store = new JSONObject(response);
if(store.has("CreatedOn")) {
Integer datetimestamp = Integer.parseInt(store.getString("CreatedOn").replaceAll("\\D", ""));
 Date date = new Date(datetimestamp);
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
 String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
}
```

consider using JSON methods instead of contains. JSON has "has()" which validate if key exists.

You should also make sure that you try {} catch {} the String first, to make sure its valid JSON.

Update:

Your Value is 
    /Date(1406192939581)/

which means it must be formatted first. 
Get it by parsing the string with

```
Integer datetimestamp = Integer.parseInt(store.getString("CreatedOn").replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

It’s about time that someone provides the modern answer. When this question was asked in 2014, Java 8 had just come out, and with it java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Today I recommend we all use this and avoid the old classes `Timestamp`, `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` used in the other answer. The old classes were poorly designed and were replaced for a good reason.

**Edit:** With Java 8 you can directly parse your string from JSON into an `Instant` using an advanced formatter, which I consider quite elegant:

```
    DateTimeFormatter jsonDateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLiteral("/Date(")
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .appendLiteral(")/")
            .toFormatter();

    String createdOn = "/Date(1406192939581)/";
    Instant created = jsonDateFormatter.parse(createdOn, Instant::from);
    System.out.println("Created on " + created);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Created on 2014-07-24T09:08:59.581Z

The formatter knows that the last 3 digits are milliseconds of the second and considers all the preceding digits seconds since the epoch, so this works the way it should. To count the days of difference from CreatedOn Date to Present Date:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Antarctica/South_Pole");
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(created.atZone(zone).toLocalDate(), LocalDate.now(zone));
    System.out.println("Days of difference: " + days);
```

Output today (2019-12-20):

> Days of difference: 1975

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Antarctica/South_Pole.

**Original answer:**

```
    final Pattern jsonDatePattern = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/");

    String createdOn = "/Date(1406192939581)/";
    Matcher dateMatcher = jsonDatePattern.matcher(createdOn);
    if (dateMatcher.matches()) {
        Instant created = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(dateMatcher.group(1)));
        System.out.println("Created on " + created);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Invalid format: " + createdOn);
    }
```

Output is:

> Created on 2014-07-24T09:08:59.581Z

I am using a regular expression not only to extract the number from the string, but also for validation of the string.

The modern `Instant` class represents a point in time. It’s `toString` method renders the time in UTC, so this is what you see in the output, denoted by the trailing `Z`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

### [`Instant#ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-)

The key here is to get an object of `Instant` out of the milliseconds in the JSON string. Once you have `Instant`, you can convert it to other [java.time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) e.g. `ZonedDateTime` or even to the legacy `java.util.Date`.

**A note on the regex, `\D+`**: `\D` specifies a [non-digit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) while `+` specifies  its [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) occurrence(s).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject store = new JSONObject("{\n" + "\"CreatedOn\" : \"\\/Date(1406192939581)\\/\"\n" + "}");
        if (store.has("CreatedOn")) {
            // Replace all non-digits i.e. \D+ with a blank string
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(store.getString("CreatedOn").replaceAll("\\D+", "")));
            System.out.println(instant);

            // Now you can convert Instant to other java.time types e.g. ZonedDateTime
            // ZoneId.systemDefault() returns the time-zone of the JVM. Replace it with the
            // desired time-zone e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
            ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            // Print the default format i.e. the value of zdt#toString
            System.out.println(zdt);

            // A custom format
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String strDateTimeFormatted = zdt.format(dtf);
            System.out.println(strDateTimeFormatted);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-07-24T09:08:59.581Z
2014-07-24T10:08:59.581+01:00[Europe/London]
Thu July 24 10:08:59 2014
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### How to get `java.util.Date` from an `Instant`:

You should avoid using `java.util.Date` but for whatsoever purpose, if you want to get `java.util.Date`, all you have to do is to use [`Date#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) as shown below:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```