# Convert part of string to java.util.Date

Tags: java, c#, json, exception, date-conversion

I am posting DateTime as JSON and it becomes "/Date(1512839439513)/"

i simply want to convert

```
"/Date(1512839439513)/"  to java.util.Date
```

I have tried this

```
String date = finalObject.getString("DateCreated");
String datereip = date.replaceAll("\\D+","");
Long timeInMillis = Long.parseLong(datereip);
Date date1=new Date(timeInMillis);
```

But did not worked...

Comment: If it did not work, what did it do instead? What did you expect it to do? What did you find when you debugged it?

Comment: Why is this tagged both with java and c#? What date this this number represents? (seems like epoch time)

Comment: `System.out.println(new Date(Long.parseLong("/Date(1512839439513)/".replaceAll("\\D+",""))));` outputs `Sat Dec 09 19:10:39 EET 2017`, so the question is what is returned by `finalObject.getString("DateCreated")`. Have you used a debugger before?

Comment: Why don't you send the date in a standardized format instead of whatever that is?

Comment: @JoeC agree, this has nothing to valid JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json date to java date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956396/convert-json-date-to-java-date)

Comment: Please for your own sake search before posting your question. This one has been asked and answered a couple of times before.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are asking for an instance of the long outmoded `Date` class? Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you extract the milliseconds from the string seems to be the problem.

You can try this to extract needed data from the string:

```
String date = finalObject.getString("DateCreated");

String temp = date.substring(date.indexOf("(") + 1);
String datereip = date.substring(0, date.indexOf(")"));

Long timeInMillis = Long.parseLong(datereip);
Date date1=new Date(timeInMillis);
```

This assumes that the date string will have only one pair of parenthesis. Also, there are better ways to [extract string between 2 chars with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters) but that is a topic of another question.

Comment: what is s << in 4th line?

Comment: Edited the code to for Java. Sry about that. `s` was meant to be `date`

Comment: got exception
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1

Comment: You should check does your `date` string that you get from `finalObject` really contain 2 parenthesis and is not empty.

Comment: Seems like your `finalObject.getString("DateCreated")` returns a string that is 4 char long and doesn't contain any parenthesis. Use a debugger or print the result of the method to console